# How to find the pdb or dll location for symbols you have already loaded?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

If I am debugging something in Visual Studio, and I am looking through the call stack, and some code in the stack is external code, and I click to Load Symbols for that code, and the symbols load, and I can now browse through the source code... **where on my file system is the pdb that those symbols were loaded from?**

Regardless of which symbol server those symbols are loaded from, as far as I am aware, there has to be a file somewhere on my file system that is storing a pdb or dll or similar that allowed Visual Studio to decompile the source code.

Where can I find this?

Comment: Debug > Windows > Modules.  Right-click the DLL in that list > Symbol Load Information shows where the PDB came from.

Comment: Does Hans' answer solve your problem? Or any update about the issue?

Comment: @HansPassant answer does indeed solve my problem. He should put it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can actually also find the loaded symbol files/pdb under the External Sources folder in Solution Explorer. This is available for Visual Studio 22.

read here : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugging-external-sources-with-visual-studio/